# How can I display nii.gz segmentation data into 3D model on website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, image-segmentation

I tried to use three.js to display nii.gz images but it was a headache.

I don't know what I did wrong so I tried another method which is generate the 3D model using python. I was using MyVi but there was too many errors.

I searched and read many thesis articles. Mostly, they only display their segmentation result on python. I need to do this on website though.

Is there any direct and simpler method to display nii.gz on website?

As mentioned, if python to javascript (I'm using React and Three.js) works, please tell me how to do it!

If not, please tell me what are solutions!!

Thanks

Comment: Hi, maybe can you provide more information or atleast screenshot of data what you need display? I google nii.gz format and it looks like 2d image format. You need somehow show this data in 3D or just in 2D?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.